# Loading a Dictionary of Objects from a binary file c#

Tags: c#, dictionary, deserialization

My program saves a dictionary of objects to a binary file and then can load that dictionary later.

From what I can tell, my save function is working.

```
public void GenerateFactionFile()
        {

            try
            {

                FileStream writerFileStream =
                    new FileStream(@"../../../Files/factions.bin", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

                this.formatter.Serialize(writerFileStream, this.ListOfFactions);


                writerFileStream.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unable to save our friends' information");
            } 
        }
```

But I'm guessing it is in my save that things are going wrong.

```
        public new void Load(string currentFile)
    {


        if (File.Exists(currentFile))
        {

            try
            {

                FileStream readerFileStream = new FileStream(currentFile,
                    FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

                this.ListOfFactions = (Dictionary<int, FactionObject>)
                    this.formatter.Deserialize(readerFileStream);

                readerFileStream.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("There seems to be a file that contains " +
                    "friends information but somehow there is a problem " +
                    "with reading it.");
            } 

        } 

    }
```

Because when I try to load and place the information from the dictionary into an itemList, I get this error informing me that the first item in the dictionary isn't there...

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

That and my searching through the dictionary when that exception is thrown shows it empty.

For the sake if information, this is what a default Faction Object looks like

```
 [Serializable]
    public class FactionObject
    {

        public string factionName = string.Empty;
        public int espionage = 0;
        public int diplomacy = 0;
        public int mechanized = 0;
        public int armoured = 0;
        public int airAssault = 0;
        public int airCav = 0;
        public int airSuper = 0;
        public int airSupport = 0;
        public float overall = 0.0f;
        public CharacterObject[] characterArray = new CharacterObject[2];
        public int CharacterStartPoints;
    }
```

Comment: why not use `BinaryFormatter. Serialize` and why not use plain text files?

Comment: @Ravajava Lei Yang's comment is spot on. no need to reinvent the wheel